# Why my parameters in loop for is not updated

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file

I try to loop into all files in a folder and split filesnames to use them as input argument in a batch file.

Could somebody explain me please why when I enter in my loop FOR for the 2nd times (and so on), my variables inside the loop for seems no more updated/recognize ?

When I try to display the FILENAME variable, I had "echo FILENAME : !FILENAME!" but I expected "echo FILENAME : myfile.txt

Same issue when I called the PRINT batch with 2 arguments, I expected to execute my batch with "D:\App\Test\print.bat" testfolder myfile.txt" but I saw "D:\App\Test\print.bat" !arg1! !arg2!"

I was thinking it should be due to the ENABLEDELAYEXPANSION which end at the end of the first loop but my endlocal ENABLEDELAYEXPANSION has been put at the end of my batch.

So I do not really understand what happen...

Thank you very much for your help!

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%i in ("D:\App\Result"\*.*) do (

   echo name : %%i
   set str=%%i

   for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=\" %%a in ("!str!") do (set DRIVELETTER=%%a&set DOMAIN=%%b&set NAME=%%c&set RESULT=%%d&set FILENAME=%%e)

   echo FILENAME: !FILENAME!

   set FOLDERNAME=!str:~0,5!
   echo FOLDERNAME : !FOLDERNAME!

   set arg1="D:\App\!FOLDERNAME!"
   set arg2="D:\App\!FILENAME!"
    
   D:\App\Test\print.bat !arg1! !arg2!

 )

 endlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

Comment: Are you saying that it fails the second time you run the script, or on the second file that the loop finds?

Comment: Did you know that to get the file name it is as easy as: `%%~nxi`.  I am not understanding your usage of the variables `FOLDERNAME` and `ARG1`. You are doing a substring of the `STR` variable which would make the value of `FOLDERNAME` be `D:\Ap` and the value of `ARG1` be `"D:\App\D:\Ap"`.

Comment: Also if you need to run a batch file from another batch file and wish for execution to return to the parent batch file then you need to use the `CALL` command to execute the child batch file.

Comment: Also the `ENDLOCAL` command has no arguments supplied to it.  The only thing on the line should be `ENDLOCAL`.

Comment: The `FILENAME` variable will never be populated.  There are only 4 tokens to your file path. **1)** D: **2)** App **3)** Result **4)** Filename.  The 5th token is never populated.

Comment: Before you do anything further on StackOverFlow, I implore you to take the [tour] and read [ask] a good question. Then [edit] your question to provide a better [mcve] of the code you are using.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for all your comments, I'll try to edit my question to provide a better example.